# [Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Location "imageURL" isn't readable - Expo React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks, expo

I am trying to convert an firebase image URL to base64 using expo FileSystem but getting following error.

> [Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Location "https://pngimg.com/uploads/birds/small/birds_PNG108.png" isn't readable - Expo React Native

URL is totally fine and perfect as I can open it in browser. I am trying following URL, and tried multiple other URLs as well.

```
https://pngimg.com/uploads/birds/small/birds_PNG108.png
```

Following is my code.

```
import * as FileSystem from 'expo-file-system';
<TouchableOpacity onPress={async () => {
      const base64 = await FileSystem.readAsStringAsync('https://pngimg.com/uploads/birds/small/birds_PNG108.png', { encoding: 'base64' });
        Share.share(
          {
            title: 'test title',
            url: item.url,
          },
          {
            excludedActivityTypes: [
              
            ],
          }
        );
     }}>
    </TouchableOpacity>
    
  )}
```

Couldn't find any solution to this problem on any forum.

Comment: AFAIK  `FileSystem.readAsStringAsync` is for URI and not an URL.
Download the file store it in `FileSystem.documentDirectory/…`.

Then you can access stored file with `FileSystem.readAsStringAsync`

Comment: Thank You, it's converting to base64 now but when i share, it says can't send empty message. You have any idea about that?

Comment: Also please post it as answer so I can accept it for others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should rather use

`import * as Sharing from 'expo-sharing';`

Save the image temporary on disc and use the uri to share the image.

than

`import { Share} from 'react-native';`

Comment: I am getting `can't send empty message error`

Answer (score 1):

### You can work like this

I am Passing the values from another component

```
import { Share } from "react-native";
import * as Sharing from "expo-sharing";
import * as FileSystem from "expo-file-system";
import { cacheDirectory, downloadAsync } from "expo-file-system";
const onShare = async (title, message, url, image) => {
    // console.log(image[0])
  const messageAndUrl = message.concat("\n\n").concat(url);
  try {
    url = image[0];
    // console.log({url})
        const uri = await downloadAsync(url , cacheDirectory + "tmp.png");
        console.log({uri}); // it prints a local image file
        // Share.share({url : uri.uri , message : messageAndUrl });
    const result = await Share.share(
      {
        title,
        url : uri.uri ,
        message: messageAndUrl,
      },
      {
        subject: title,
      }
    );
    if (result.action === Share.sharedAction) {
      // Always work with android
      if (result.activityType) {
        // worked
      } else {
        // shared
      }
    } else if (result.action === Share.dismissedAction) {
      // run only for ios if share is dismissed
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

export default { onShare };
```