# Share image and text with expo

Tags: react-native, expo

I have an Expo application that generates an image from a map. I need to share that image along with a text.

Using expo-sharing, I can share only the image without any text.

Using Share from react-native, I can share only text without any image.

Unfortunately, the library react-native-share does not work with Expo managed workflows, so it's not an option.

Is there ANY alternative to overcome this?

Tried this: https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/sharing/, but only image

Tried this: https://reactnative.dev/docs/share, but only text

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem before and I had to make my app again without expo in order to use react-native-share, my app was simple so it was easy, but I found this example for another user here in stackoverflow [user post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69119423/unhandled-promise-rejection-error-location-imageurl-isnt-readable-expo-r/75131356#75131356), I don't know if it works but you can try it.

Seems like there is no much documentation about sharing images and text at the same time with expo. Please share if you found another solution